# How do you programmatically add an annotation in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Google analytics supports annotations (see: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-analytics-annotations/ ). I would like to add a call to add an annotation to our Google Analytics property in our deployment script.

Answer (score 8):

I find out that you cannot, **yet**. 
See https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=53

It was a feature requested 7 years ago and people keep regularly adding "+1".

Considering that Google Analytics does not have its own Google Product Group open to discussions (only a group for notifications to the users: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-analytics-api-notify ), I hope that somebody in their team is listening and can bring this feature request up to the management.

Comment: It's coming!  After 10 years it's coming.  https://www.wissi.fr/blog/analytics/20200401/google-data-studio-annotations-as-in-google-analytics/